# Why it keep saying No database selected?

Tags: php

I am trying to create print report on my my homework. But, it keep saying "No Database Selected". Here's my code

```
 <?php

    include "../database/database.php";
    require('../laporan/fpdf/fpdf.php');

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
```

and

```
    $no =1;
    $query=mysql_query("select * from data_tamu");
    if ($query === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error());
        }
    while($lihat=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    }




    $server = "localhost";
     $user = "root";
     $pass = "";
     $data = "data_tamu,php";


     $pdf->Output("aselole.pdf", "Y"); // ditampilkan

    ?>
```

Do you guys know where's my fault? I don't know where it is. Please help me

Comment: What is content of "../database/database.php"?

Comment: Where do you connect to your database? Please note that mysql_* functions are removed in PHP7 and deprecated in previous versions. It's a good idea to switch to [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) before you go any further to save yourself headaches later.

Comment: you're putting the wagon before the horse here

Comment: First of all, you should stop using mysql_* functions since they're deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO_* instead. And I think your error is simply that you've nowhere selected a db. I think you're missing something like `mysql_select_db( 'TUTORIALS' );` (bad example, since you really should use mysqli or PDO!!!!) And as Fred said, all those connection informations shouldn't be there in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Before querying, you must select which database on your server you are using. This is done using the [`mysql_select_db`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) function. I suppose this is what is missing from you `database.php`

You can call the function just like this:

```
mysql_select_db('db_name');
```

However, remember that these functions are **deprecated** since PHP5.5 and you should use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or any other alternative that uses prepared statements!

Comment: Currently there is Absolutely No Information in the question about whats in the `include "../database/database.php";` So assuming OP just missed the selecting of the database is a bit premature